# Install Angular library dependencies

Tags: angular, angular-library

I'm using **Angular 8**. As per the business requirement, there is an isolated application that is separate from the main application but will be used in the main application.

For that I created a `library` using the command

```
ng generate library my-library
```

The **my-library/package.json** has following dependencies

```
{
  "name": "my-library",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.14",
    "ngx-device-detector": "^1.4.5",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.26",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.12.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.12.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.12.0",
    "ngx-spinner": "^9.0.2"
  }
}
```

The library is inside the application in the `project` directory, thus the directory structure is

```
|- app
   |- package
      |- my-library
         |- src/
         |- package.json     # Library dependencies
   |- src                    # Main application
      |- app
      |- environments
   |- angular.json
   |- package.json           # Application dependencies
```

I installed the dependencies from `/app` directory

```
npm install
```

Then building the library using

```
ng build my-library
```

But this gives the error

```
...
Cannot find module 'ngx-device-detector'
...
```

**How can I install the library dependencies?**

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't navigate to the library folder. Go to the terminal and enter the following command: `cd app/package/my-library`, this command navigates you to the library directory. It could be different depending on what your starting point is. Run the `ng build` command once you navigated to the library folder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the **path** of your library into main project **package.json**

"@my-library": "file:./package/my-library"